# Plot linestrings above each other with sf in a loop

Tags: r

I have a linestring, which I would like to copy 2 times and place above the original with a shift in the latitude of 2 meters each.

The data from the original linestring looks as follows:

```
ID <- c(1:3)
long <- c(1,2,3)
lat <- c(1,2,1)

a <- data.frame(cbind(ID, long, lat))

line <- a %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

The result from the operation would look like the image below, with the original linestring being the lowest line in the graph and the 2 copies above that one. Is there a nice way to loop this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact, that adding point geometry moves feature(s) by vector:

```r
ID <- c(1:3)
long <- c(1,2,3)
lat <- c(1,2,1)

a <- data.frame(cbind(ID, long, lat))

line <- a |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) |>
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) |>
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")

for (i in c(1:5)) {
  aa <- (line$geometry[[1]]+sf::st_point(c(0,2*i))) |>
    sf::st_sfc() |>
    sf::st_as_sf() |>
    dplyr::rename(geometry = x)
  
  line <- line |>
    rbind(aa)
  
}

plot(line, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Grzegorz!

Comment: Note that you should `st_transform` to a CRS that uses meters as the primary unit first, then `st_transform` back to lat-long (4326) after. Otherwise you'll be adding degrees and not meters.

Comment: For affine transformation you can actually skip `st_point()` conversion, just `line$geometry + c(0,2)` would do.